# Install and use tensorflow_docs with Jupyter Notebook

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-lab

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression but I get some error when I try to import tenroflow_docs. 
As mentioned in the tutorial, I installed tensorflow_docs with the following command: `!pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs`. The installation seemed to have worked as I get the message: *"Successfully built tensorflow-docs"*.

However, when I want to import the package by writing (as per the tutorial) `import tensorflow_docs as tfdocs` I get the error message shown in the picture below.

How can I correct this? Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: I have noticed that this message appeared during your installation **"Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable"**
The problem is that the default install location is a place where you do not have write permissions. The solution is to use an install location where you do have write permissions. Have you tried using a virtual environment instead? this is a better practice and might be the easier solution let me know if you have tried it first.

Comment: Hei,
Thank you for your answer. I have not tried using a virtual environment.I will try that and see if it works. 
Thanks

Comment: Happy to help. Kindly keep us updated on the result. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it works with a virtual environment. Thanks!

Comment: Great to know it works. I have posted it as an answer to this problem kindly mark as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: @SamR  How do I work on a virtual enviroment? can you share hints with me?

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that this message appeared during your installation ***"Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable"***

The problem is that a default install location is a place where you do not have write permissions. The solution is to use an install location where you do have write permissions.
Have you tried using a **virtual environment** instead? this is a better practice and might be an easier solution.